# c# - Newtonsoft.Json Exception: Having problem serializing IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, ienumerable

The exception message I get:
'Constructor for 'BPlusTreeLeaf`1[System.Int32]' must have no parameters or a single parameter that implements 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]'

My class properties and constructor for desiralizaing:

```
public class BPlusTreeNode<T> : IEnumerable<string> where T : IComparable
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    protected List<T> keys = null;
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    protected List<string> paths = null;
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    protected bool isLeaf = false;
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    protected int order;
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    protected string path;
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    protected string next = null;
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    protected string prev = null;

    [JsonConstructor]
    public BPlusTreeNode(List<T> keys, List<string> paths, bool isLeaf,
        string path, string next, string prev, int order = 10)
    {
        this.keys = keys;
        this.paths = paths;
        this.isLeaf = isLeaf;
        this.path = path;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.order = order;

    }
```

I also have a class inheriting from BPlusTreeNode:

```
public class BPlusTreeLeaf<T> : BPlusTreeNode<T> where T : IComparable

    [JsonConstructor]
    public BPlusTreeLeaf(List<T> keys, List<string> paths, bool isLeaf,
        string path, string next, string prev, int order = 10) :
            base(keys, paths, isLeaf, path, next, prev, order)
    {
    }
```

And the serialization part:

```
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(filePath);
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.Serialize(file, node);
        file.Close();
        file.Dispose();
```

exception happens on serializer.Serialize(file, node)

Any suggestion what's wrong with my implementation?
Thanks in advance!

**Edit: I found the problem**:
The serializer by default will serialize a class inheriting from IEnumerable
as... of course an IEnumerable.
The solution is to put the JsonObjectAttribue above the class.

Comment: The message is pretty clear. Your type, `BPlusTreeNode<T>`, needs to have either a default constructor or a constructor that accepts one parameter of a type that implements `IEnumerable<string>`. You have neither.

Comment: Thanks!
wouldn't it change how the class is serialized?

Comment: You need to do the science. Try it out and see what happens.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. The deserializer can instantiate the collection only by a default constructor (in which case the collection should have a working `ICollection<T>.Add` implementation) or by an initializer collection. But your constructor has a lot of arguments. As they just initialize some members consider to expose them as publicly settable properties so the serializer can handle them.

Comment: @picki23 is the issue fixed for you? I see when we add JsonObject Attribute, $type and $value properties gets added in response.